# Doing a disk copy with dd on RAID1 devices on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raid, dd

I want to make exact copies of two drives using dd. The two drives are mounted on Ubuntu as a single RAID1 device. The RAID (consisting of two drives) is bootable. If I make exact copies of the two drives using dd and then used them on another machine (after disconnecting the old machine to avoid IP address conflicts) will there be any  issues?
I am planning to bring the source machine down, then just move the drives to another machine, not mount them, then do a dd on them as source to two other drives on the new machine.

What needs to be done to the new drives before I run dd? For example, do I have to partition them to match the source drives?

Here is the output of lsblk on the source machine:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0  29.8G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0  29.8G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sda2    8:2    0 901.7G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0 901.6G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0  29.8G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0  29.8G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sdb2    8:18   0 901.7G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0 901.6G  0 raid1 /
```

**POST-ANSWER**

Here is the output of "sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0" after I added one new drive to the RAID:

```
 /dev/md0:
            Version : 1.2 
      Creation Time : Wed Aug 29 18:00:28 2018
         Raid Level : raid1
         Array Size : 31232000 (29.79 GiB 31.98 GB) 
      Used Dev Size : 31232000 (29.79 GiB 31.98 GB) 
       Raid Devices : 2 
      Total Devices : 3 
        Persistence : Superblock is persistent

        Update Time : Tue Jan  2 18:33:14 2024
              State : clean 
     Active Devices : 2 
    Working Devices : 3 
     Failed Devices : 0 
      Spare Devices : 1 

 Consistency Policy : resync

               Name : august2018:0  (local to host august2018)
               UUID : cec496a6:b34bde28:4a56871f:8dffc234
             Events : 300094

     Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
        2       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
        1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1

        3       8       33        -      spare   /dev/sdc1
```

**Can you explain the "State" column at the bottom?**

Also, "cat /proc/mdstat" displays:

```
 Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
 md1 : active raid1 sdc2[2](S) sda2[1] sdb2[0]
       945379328 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
       bitmap: 1/8 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

 md0 : active raid1 sdc1[3](S) sda1[1] sdb1[2]
       31232000 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Comment: I don't think `dd` is the best solution for that. A good solution would be to add 2 others drives inside the (mdadm ?) RAID 1. - First, create exact same partitions with `sfdisk -d /dev/sd[a-b] | sfdisk /dev/new_drive`, then add both partitions inside the `md0` and `md1` and to finish install `grub` with `grub-install /dev/sd[a-b]`on both new drives.

Comment: @hidigoudi  Sounds good. Can you post it as an answer with full commands? I will certainly accept it. I am not a full-time admin and am afraid that I may mess up the original drives. Besides, it will be very informative for others too.

Comment: Done. I will edit my answer as I go along to add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution **only works** with same size's drives as you current production drives (`931.5G`).

---

#### First step (only for your new drives)

Make sure that your new drives have **no partition and are clean of data**. You can perform these commands to clear drives :

```
wipefs -a /dev/your_new_drive
```

**OR / AND**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/your_new_drive status=progress bs=1M count=5000 && sync
```

This will erase partitions / meta-data / signatures of present partitions.

**Caution :** These are dangerous and irreversible commands, do not use the wrong disks.

#### Second step

Mirror the existing partitions table on the 2 new disks by using this command :

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/your_new_drive
```

You need to perform this command on your both new drives.

This will copy the current partitions table of production drives in the new.

After this step, you should have 2 partitions of `29.8G` and `901.7G`.

#### Third step

Include new partitions in the both `mdadm` `RAID 1`.

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdX1
mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sdX2
```

Once all is added, you should see your new drives tagged as `spare` inside the array definition (`mdadm --detail /dev/mdX`). To grow the RAID 1 `Raid Devices` number to X devices and start the resync, you need to use these commands :

```
mdadm --grow -n X /dev/md0
mdadm --grow -n X /dev/md1
```

`X` should be the number you want of **active devices** in the array.

You need to perform those commands twice for your 2 new drives.

Then wait the `resync` of the both RAIDs (`md0` should be quick).

You can consult the speed and the time remaining with this command

```
watch -n0.5 cat /proc/mdstat
```

After that, your new drives should be tagged as `active sync` inside the `mdadm --detail /dev/mdX` output.

If one drive of your array is still not synced (still tagged as `spare`), you would use this command :

```
mdadm --readwrite /dev/mdX
```

This will force the `resync`.

#### Fourth step

You are almost done. You just need to be sure that `grub` is correctly installed on your 2 new drives

```
grub-install /dev/your_new_drive
```

Perform this command on your 2 new drives (take care to have `grub` installed **on all drives**). Then :

```
update-initramfs -u
```

#### Importants notes

This process **should not** be dangerous for your data because it does not affect the disks in production (only `read` operations (also `write` if you install `grub` on the production drives)). However, **be very careful** while executing all those commands (especially those from the first step).

If you have any question before making an action, feel free to add a comment under this answer.

Comment: I was thinking of rebooting the system with just one RAID drive at a time, clone that drive, remove the new drive, re-connect the removed RAID drive, reboot, check if all is OK and then repeat the process with the next drive. This way, I am sure that no matter how badly I mess things, at least one RAID drive will be available for the system to be up. I suspect that this may not work in view of grub internal table. What do you think?

Comment: Theoretically you can do it like that since it's a `RAID 1` and all the data are on all the disks (mirroring). You should boot with only 1 drive. Once again, it's only read operations on your current drives.

Comment: Be sure that `grub` is correctly installed on the boot drive. - Note by doing this that `mdadm` will tagged your both RAID as `degraded` as you will have only 1 drive for few seconds while the new drive is added.

Comment: But when both original drives are reconnected and booted, I guess I will have to run mdadm again with appropriate options to get them to sync.  If I follow your original approach, after adding the two new drives and then disconnecting them, will mdadm tag them as degraded? Or will min two drives suffice to not tag them as degraded?

Comment: It will be fine with 2 drives. No sync will be require for original drives. - It's just a temporary state. - With a RAID 1, you don't risk much. - The original drives will only be used to synchronize the 2 new ones.

Comment: I went thru steps suggested by you but for only one new disk at this time. I find that "mdadm --detail /dev/md0" shows "STATE" of "/dev/sda1" and "/dev/sdb1" as "active sync" while that of the newly added "/dev/sdc1" as "spare"  I have not yet added grub-install at this time not knowing if the synchronization is complete. Please HELP!

Comment: Please see the section added to my question at the end. It lists the output of mdadm --detail /dev/md0  as well as of "cat /proc/mdstat"

Comment: It's fine, you did well, the `spare` tag is normal as you current RAID has 2 devices. See here : `Raid Devices : 2`. It does not affect data. You can continue with your last drive.

Comment: Should it be "grub-install /dev/sdc" or "grub-install /dev/sdc2"? You implied "grub-install /dev/sdc" I need to read on grub to understand this but for now I need to install it. Thanks for all your help

Comment: It's `grub-install /dev/sdc`.

Comment: Done installing grub. Final question: So now I should be able to boot with just /dev/sdc connected without the other two drives though I plan to have another drive added to the RAID too.  If I can boot the system with just the new drive, then the newly added RAID drive is kind of complete backup of the system as of today.

Comment: Exactly, RAID 1 also called `mirroring` has the exact same data on all disks. All drives are exactly the same (**after the resync**).

Comment: Thought that was the final question. I tried to boot with just the new drive and I got the error:  disk 'mduuid....' not found. Entering rescue mode. Then there is the "grub rescue>' prompt.

Comment: Ok, yes it's an error with the UUID of the disk. Indeed, I will add this information in my answer. Could you please reboot with your original drives + your 2 new one ? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150614/discussion-between-hidigoudi-and-sunny).

Comment: @Sunny, I added commands to extend raid devices number. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: The problem I think was that the new disc does not get synced until we run the command with the --grow option as pointed out by you. I tried to boot with one old drive and the new drive only. It started syncing now and is taking a lot of time to sync 901.7 GB.  That syncing certainly did not happen when we just added the third drive.  It will take another 30 minutes to sync. I will then try booting with just the new drive and see.  With two drives, the swap partition at this time for the new drive still shows as "spare" while the bigger partition shows as "spare rebuilding"

Comment: All works well now. All combinations. Was able to boot from just the third drive only which was the main intent. It is the off-site backup as of today of the entire system. All other combinations work fine too.  DO NOT KNOW HOW TO THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR TIME.

Comment: Ok great, sounds good to me. I updated my answer again, indeed some mistakes were still present in it. Thank you !

Comment: Regarding "disks in production (only read operation)"  Installing grub again on those drives, in theory, is a write operation. Also, the newly installed raid drive may be in read-only state until the first write. It is only after that that it starts syncing. There is a way around it. Do a mdadm --readwrite on mdX I had this problem with the swap partition because I think that the RAM is so big that there was no write (swapping) so I had to force a --readwrite to sync.  May be you want to add that. YOUR ANSWER WILL SERVE MANY.  You have simplified a complex subject into simple steps.